# Java - pass elements of a list as parameters to an unlimited-arguments method

Tags: java

I have a method with unlimited parameters:

```
void X(Object... values){};
```

And a unknown list that the user should input.

Now I want to pass all the elements of that list to method X, like

```
this.X(list.get(0), list.get(1)......);
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Look into `List#toArray(..)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A method declared as

```
void X(Object... values){};
```

is similar to a method declared as

```
void X(Object[] values){};
```

and can be called with an `Object[]`, though only the first can be called with a variable number of arguments.  You can convert your list to an array of using [List.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29), so that you can call `X(list.toArray())`.  Here's example code demonstrating:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class VarargsExample {

    public static void foo( Object... args ) { 
        System.out.println( "foo: "+Arrays.toString( args ));
    }

    public static void bar( Object[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "bar: "+Arrays.toString( args ));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // only foo can be called with variable arity arguments
        foo( 1, 2, 3 );
        // bar( 4, 5, 6 ); // won't compile 

        // both methods can be called with object arrays
        foo( new Object[] { 7, 8, 9 } );
        bar( new Object[] { 10, 11, 12 } );

        // so both can be called with List#toArray results
        foo( Arrays.asList( 13, 14, 15 ).toArray() );
        bar( Arrays.asList( 16, 17, 18 ).toArray() );
    }
}
```

```
foo: [1, 2, 3]
foo: [7, 8, 9]
bar: [10, 11, 12]
foo: [13, 14, 15]
bar: [16, 17, 18]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass individual items or an array of items to such a varargs method.  Convert your list to an array to pass it in, using the [`toArray` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29):

```
this.X(list.toArray());
```

Comment: Just a small addition if you need a specific object type to be returned by List.toArray(), do it like this: String[] a = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);